# IOS Organizer doesn't show status as "submitted"

Tags: ios, app-store

I just now validated and submitted my iPhone app to the the app store via the organizer. It was accepted, but the status column doesn't, or is not yet showing a status of "submitted" as it has previously. Is it a matter of waiting, or is there something I missed?

Comment: Nope, doesn't show it for me either anymore. Not sure what's up :[

Comment: Ok, I'll just wait it out. Thanks.

Comment: Are you checking status of app or app's binary? which screen your were referring?

Comment: You can wait… but… I think it’s a little bug in Xcode - I send a few app one month ago… and doesn’t show any status :)